# Dynamically Skype Web Control tags

Tags: javascript

I can't make call and video call after I put Skype web control. It shows this issue:

> Skype web control blob does not exist.

So, what can I do to find solution for this issue?

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your code.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="skype-button bubble " data-contact-id="kk.89"></div>
<script src="http://swc.cdn.skype.com/sdk/v1/sdk.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:b45b3293-101e-010d-1f0f-324dbd000000 Time:2018-08-12T07:40:17.3868577Z
</Message>
</Error>